# Android : How to give country-wise update for beta application from the google play console?

Tags: android, google-play-console, release-management, beta

I have gone through some links for help, where I found that this is possible in the google play console.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7550024?hl=en https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6346149#zippy=%2Crelease-a-staged-rollout-to-specific-countries

We have one app in the play store since last 5 years and uploaded more than 200 updates. Know we need to set up a country-wise rollout. like if I upload app in the beta(open testing) and after testing, i want to roll out for 2 countries like UAE and Saudi Arabia. and after that, I want to roll out for other regions.

If yes, Is there need to create a separate app for all the regions? or we can just roll out the same app to the other regions from the beta?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delayed response. I got the solution and found it worth sharing, so answering my own question.

For stagged rollout [Percentage wise or country wise], We need to enable "Managed Publishing" you can get more details from this link [Control app publishing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859654?hl=en)

Once you enable, You can handle when app should be send to review, when you need to publish app in the play store etc. also you can handle publishing of other content changes. like app content, screen shots, desc etc

You will get all update in publish overview.

[image: Publishing overview]

After this setup, When you release app to production, open testing, close testing, you will have option after reviewing you app, you can choose which country you want to release and also percentage of the rolling out. you can select any number of percentage from 0 to 100 for rollout.

Cheers.